# Website response on request for URL's not as expected

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking to load a website and collect all of the links which is normally pretty straightforward, however I had this weird response today:

```
links = WebDriverWait(web, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//a[@href]')))
print("This is what is showing for links", links) # Debug
```

> This is what is showing for links
> [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="33f088aa2028ccf3e49527ba2bbf4648",
> element="ba0c173a-a4ae-4b91-a166-42e7aa0f9f04")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="33f088aa2028ccf3e49527ba2bbf4648",
> element="833ca6d1-cc72-4830-9529-ed068680d4b7")>]

Can someone explain what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect all urls from links, try:

```
url_list = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
```